# Is there a way to simulate Beacon from a pc and recive it on the same one?

Tags: node.js, bluetooth, ibeacon, beacon

I'm implementing a **Bluetooth** infrastructure to monitoring the accesses to a building: a simple one, scanners on the doors and each person have a beacon transmitter.

I have write the scanner using [node-beacon-scanner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-beacon-scanner), that is based on *noble*, and it's working, I've tried using *Beacon Simulator* from my phone, **but but I' m missing a way to test it without using a real beacon emitter.**

I've tried using [bleno](https://github.com/noble/bleno), [node-bleacon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bleacon),
[node-red-contrib-bleacon on node-red](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-bleacon) but nothing worked.

**Is it possible to simulate a beacon from a PC and recive it from the same PC?** I'm actually working on Ubuntu 20.04 but I think I' ll move all to docker, so the OS shouldn't be a problem and every languages, if it works, is welcome.

Comment: Did you find out how to broadcast from a desktop?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I abandoned the project :(